# How can I simultaneously (from different threads) insert data into different tables in one Android SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my Android application I have SQLite database with  4 tables (laboratories,doctors,income_messages, outcome_messages). Information for this tables is retrieved from the server by using `java.lang.Thread` and after retrieving information next threads for insertion into database start.(`AsyncTask` is slow for this) and the problem that one thread can get access to database when other still inserting data.But I don't wan't to lock database just for one thread and make other threads to wait (in this case it takes a lot of time).

So the question: can i in some way allow different threads to insert the data into different tables simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html). That will solve the problem! Content Provider will handle simultaneous tables processes for you!
There are some works around like using a single instance for SQliteDatabaseHelper, it did never work did work perfectly when I was faced with a problem like yours.
When I switched to Content Provider, everything went smooth.

Answer (score 0):

The use of a single  [SQLiteDatabase](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) object, across all threads (and their hosting components), to get thread safety is recommended. DBHelper must be a singleton, or use a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html), to achieve this effect.